# Sleep Cycle - What kind of Backgroundmode is this?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, location, ios8

I'm currently working on an app which reminds the user, when he gets to an certain location. I want this app working in background as well and searched for solutions.

In the AppStore i found the App called Sleep Cycle, which tracks your activities during your sleep. When you set the alarm, and running the App in the Background you get this screen red bar on the top of the Display of your iPhone.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEejp.jpg

Does anybody know what kind of Backgroundmode this is, and how i can transfer it to my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To have such a red bar I use `audio` background mode and also I record sound in background. Since Sleep Cycle asks user to allow access to microphone I believe it also records audio in background

Comment: actually, I disabled the recording access, it still show red bar